# recursively increment a date in sql

Tags: sql, loops, data-warehouse, teradata

I am working on a historical conversion of data and was wondering if there's a more efficient way to accomplish a date increment.

I receive a data from a source system on a saturday date (1-7-13) and would like to push that data to make it fill all days of the previous week (1-6-13,1-5-13 ect).

So currently i am doing several unions

```
insert into target
(date, name)
select date,name 
from 
(
SELECT date as date, name FROM SOURCE
UNION
SELECT date - 1 as date, name FROM SOURCE
UNION
SELECT date -2 as date, name FROM SOURCE
)
```

I only ask because it looks like close to 500 million records are going to be going though this sql script.  Incase it matters it is going to be running in a BTEQ script in TERADATA.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code would be faster using `union all` rather than `union`.  `union` removes duplicates, which does not seem to be needed in this case.  If you do need them removed, then do it at the source level:

```
from (select distinct name from source)
```

Rather than doing it implicitly with `union`.

You can also try a cross join approach:

```
select date - i, name
from source cross join
     (select 0 as i union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
     ) const
```

This might be a bit faster, because it doesn't need to set up the reads to the table multiple times.

Comment: I really like the "for..next loop using a cross join" technique here.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a recursive query, but I don't think it would be much faster -- just perhaps easier to read:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursiveCTE (date, name) AS (
  SELECT date, name
  FROM Source
  UNION ALL
  SELECT r.date-1, r.name
  FROM recursiveCTE R
     JOIN Source T ON R.name = T.name AND T.date < r.date+6
 )
INSERT INTO Target (date,name)
SELECT date,name From recursiveCTE
```